# PHP: If-statement, need value of condition that triggered

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm sorry for the vaguely described title. This is what I want:

```
if($a[$f] === false || $a[$g] === false || $a[$h] === false || $a[$i] === false || $a[$j] === false)
{
  // do something
}
```

I want to do something with the condition that actually triggered the statement (if a[$f] = true and a[$g] = false, I want to do something with $g).

I know that in this case, the first statement that went true (i.e. $a[$g] == false) triggers. But is there any way to do something with $g? I've never seen this in my programming life before and can't seem to find anything about it.

Thanks in advance.

--- Edit ---

I forgot to mention: I'm using a function on all the array data. So, shortened, I get this:

```
if(valid($a[$f]) === false || valid($a[$g]) === false)
{
  // do something
}
```

--- Edit 2 ---

This piece of OOP-based PHP, where I'm in a class, is my code.

```
if($this->validatedText($product[$iName]) == false ||
            $this->validatedUrl($product[$iUrl]) == false ||
            $this->validatedNumber($product[$iTax]) == false ||
            $this->validatedValuta($product[$iPrice]) == false || 
            $this->validatedText($product[$iArticleNumber]) == false || 
            $this->validatedText($product[$iDescription]) == false || 
            $this->validatedText($product[$iMetaDescription]) == false || 
            $this->validatedText($product[$iTitle]) == false)
        {
            // do something with the first iVariable
        }
```

Comment: do a switch case! this way you know witch one is triggered!

Comment: Are you testing against all array keys? Or is that just some of them?

Comment: Do you need the short-circuiting behavior of `||`?

Comment: @anOG now that you mention it, yes. I could also foreach over them and break at the trigger. I have no idea why I didn't think of this. Thanks.

Comment: @tinyByte as you can see in my code I just posted, I'm using a lot of conditions. I'm trying to find a piece of code that uses the least space, because I have a two of switches - for other reasons - around this piece of code already.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution will be

```
if(false!==($sIndex = array_search(false, $a, 1)))
{
   //your $sIndex is first index with false value
}
```

if you want all keys, you may use `array_filter()`, like this:

```
$rgFalse = array_keys(array_filter($a, function($x)
{
   //here valid is your function
   return false===valid($x);
}));
```

Comment: @StefanSchouten then add your `valid` call to check (I've updated)

Comment: Ok, you know what, I'm going to post my code. I'm stumbling upon a lot of problems now.